# MVC button sending parameters from JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

So I have a panel with 3 DDL, 2 TextBoxes, a `Cancel` button and an `Apply` button. I want my button work this way:
When I click it, I want it to take the data from 3 DDL and 2 TextBoxes and build a model, send it to my controller/function and refresh the gridview .

But the function also has to check there is no duplicate entries.

So if that function returns a partial view, in case the entry I am adding is duplicated, how can I show a message to display the error?

button:

```
<button id="btnAddUpdateConfig" name="btnAddUpdateConfig" value="Apply" onclick="ValidateValues()">Apply</button>
```

My problem also comes before that; how can I send the values to the controller function? Is there a way to call a controller method passing values from the button?
But that method will have to refresh the gridview if the item is added or show and error if it is not.

If I want to do it from JS, how can I do the same?
I just know Ajax.ActionLink and that creates a link when I just want to call a controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how can I send the values to the controller function? Is there a way to call a controller method passing values from the button?`
Use jquery ajax call:

```
   function ValidateValues(){
    actionUrl=@Url.Actio("ControllerName","Action",new {param1=value,param2=value=param3=value})
    $.ajax({
    url:actionUrl,
    statusCode: {
    404: function() {
       alert("Data is duplicated");
    }
    }
    });
}
```

Now you can handle request in your action and if data is duplicate send the following code:

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "Data is duplicated");
```

Comment: Awesome, I also want to check if the textboxes types are correct, because I want in some of them integers and in other just strings.
How and where should I check that? Action? JS?